# Connection refused exception on JMeter Script Execution in VSTS

Tags: performance, jmeter, load, azure-devops, jmeter-3.2

I was trying to execute the JMeter jmx scripts in Microsoft Visual Team Services (VSTS), The scripts were working fine when executed using JMeter tool[GUI as well Non-GUI mode] but when tried to execute the same in VSTS, I was facing the below mentioned issues,

1)  Non HTTP response message: Connection refused: connect – For localhost application,

2)  Non HTTP response code: java.net.UnknownHostException – When used to run using IP address.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to test application deployed locally from Internet. Make sure you're using [public IP address instead of private](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address), you can determine it using service like [What Is My IP?](https://www.whatismyip.com/), however you need to ensure your application is not behind [NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and VSTS host(s) can reach it. It might be also a matter of [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) configuration preventing inbound connections from VSTS hosts(s).

See [Top 3 Options for Running Performance Tests Behind Your Corporate Firewall](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-three-options-running-performance-tests-behind-your-corporate-firewall) article for more information and possible solutions.